# Issue with finding the distribution of $Z\sim X+Y$ via the CDF

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y\sim\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ be independent.
If we want to find the pdf $f_Z(z)$ of $Z = X+Y$, we might try to compute this by starting with the cdf:

\begin{align*}
F_Z(z) &= \Pr[Z \leq z] \\
& = \Pr[X + Y \leq z] \\
& \color{red}{=} \Pr[X + y \leq z, Y = y] \\
& = \Pr[X \leq y-z\mid Y = y]\Pr[Y = y] \\
& = \Pr[X \leq y-z]\Pr[Y = y],\quad \text{Independence} \\
& = F_X(y-z)F_Y(y)
\end{align*}
This is clearly wrong (why would the answer be dependent on $y$ at all? What is $y$ even?).
I'm fairly confident the issue is at $\color{red}{=}$.

I'm aware of how to get the correct solution if we instead write out the definition of $\Pr[X + Y \leq z]$:
\begin{align*}
\Pr[X + Y \leq z] & = \iint_{(x,y):x+y\leq z}p_{(X,Y)}(x,y)d xd y
\end{align*}
Is there a way to solve this more similar to the (incorrect) solution I gave? Specifically, a technique that *doesn't* involve expanding $\Pr[X+Y \leq w]$ into a double integral.

---

An explicit example of the kind of proof I'd like to see can be given for the following problem:

> Let $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Find the pdf of $X = Z^2$.

The proof here can be written as:
\begin{align*}
F_X(x) &= \Pr[X\leq x] \\
& = \Pr[Z^2\leq x] \\
& = \Pr[ -\sqrt{x}\leq Z\leq \sqrt{x}] \\
& = F_Z(\sqrt{x}) - F_Z(-\sqrt{x})
\end{align*}
From here, we can take derivatives to find $f_X(x)$.

Comment: Notice that $\mathbb{P}(Y = y) = 0$ for every $y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You conditioned on "$Y=y$" but forgot to integrate over $y$ again. If you fix this, it will end up looking like the second approach that you say you understand.

Comment: @angryavian so the issue is in converting from the joint to the conditional, and not at the $\color{red}{=}$ part I denoted?

Comment: @angryavian I guess my confusion is that I learned that $\Pr(A,B) = \Pr(A\mid B)\Pr(B)$, although this is taught rather early on (and in terms of discrete probability I believe). What's the correct relationship between conditional and joint to internalize?

Comment: @Mark The issue is indeed at that line, and it should be $\int P(X+y \le z) p_Y(y) \, dy$, which is the analogue of $P(A) = \sum_i P(A \mid B_i) P(B_i)$ for a partition $\{B_1, B_2, \ldots\}$ of the sample space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing from my comments above...
\begin{align}
1 - F_Z(z)
&= P(X+Y > z)
\\
&= \int_0^\infty P(X+y > z) p_Y(y) \, dy
\\
&= \int_0^z e^{-\lambda (z-y)} \lambda e^{-\lambda y} \, dy
+ \int_z^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda y} \, dy
\\
&= \lambda z e^{-\lambda z} + e^{-\lambda z},
\end{align}
So,
$$p_Z(z)= F_Z'(z) = e^{-\lambda z} (\lambda (\lambda z + 1) - \lambda) = \lambda^2 z e^{-\lambda z}.$$